# i m unable to set bootstrap class in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, bootstrap-4

i am working on asp.net.i want to use bootstrap class in vb.net.i use following to set background color and it is working..

```
 For Each item As GridDataItem In editors_radGrid.Items
        Dim RowNo As Label = CType(item.FindControl("Editor_status"), Label)
        If RowNo.Text = "Available" Then
            RowNo.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MediumSeaGreen
        Else
            RowNo.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        End If
    Next
```

i want to set bootstrap class in the vb code...how i can do this

Comment: You could set the class by using RowNo.CssClass

Comment: Use the `CssClass` property (of the `RowNo`). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label?view=netframework-4.8#properties and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_WebControl_CssClass . Did you spend even a few moments looking into this? A simple google search would have revealed how to add a class to a label (or any other web control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set attribute to your lable, as class is attribute of the html contorl so you need to set name and value of it.

```
For Each item As GridDataItem In editors_radGrid.Items
        Dim RowNo As Label = CType(item.FindControl("Editor_status"), Label)
        If RowNo.Text = "Available" Then
            RowNo.Attribute.Add("class","You class name")
        Else
            RowNo.Attribute.Add("class","Alternative class name")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: why not use [CssClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_WebControl_CssClass) directly?

Comment: because i want change bootstrap class on the basis of condition

Comment: @Imran I wasn't actually asking you, I was asking Kevin who posted this answer. But since you replied, I can tell that wanting to change it based on a condition does not prevent you from using `.CssClass` instead of `.Attribute`

Comment: .CssClass is for asp control but once control rendered to the UI all asp controls became to html control and it you can assigned value by using attribute.Add and can remove using attribute.remove method :)

Comment: @KevinShah true, but that's irrelevant here, because if you set .CssClass this will also render the attribute in the HTML in the same way. It's just a shorter way of writing it in the VB code, that's all.